# ¿Cómo eliminar una imagen de la galería después con luego de seleccionarla con intent.ACTION_PICK?

Tags: android, kotlin

Necesito eliminar una imagen de la galería luego de seleccionarla. 
Basicamente copio la imagen a un directorio interno de la app y luego necesito borrarla de la galería.
Cuando la selecciono usando `Intent.ACTION_PICK` , solo me sucede con dispositivos que tienes google photos instalado, con otros funciona normalmente. 
El manifest tiene la solicitud de permisos.

Este es el codigo de mi intent :

```
fun selectPhoto(){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                val intentOnResult = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intentOnResult.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(intentOnResult,0)
            }else{
                requestStoragePermissions()
            }
        }
```

Luego en onActitvityResult :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
            contentResolver.delete(intent.data!!,null,null)
            pictureloaded = true
        }

    }
```

Este es el error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224
>   flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list
>   U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224}
>   }} to activity
>   {com.maxiarce.habitstracker/com.maxiarce.habitstracker.AddHabitActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
>   com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider
>   uri
>   content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224
>   from pid=9348, uid=10085 requires the provider be exported, or
>   grantUriPermission()

Perdon si no esta bien explicado, soy bastante nuevo en esto. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
>   com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider
>   uri
>   content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F32/ORIGINAL/NONE/656004224

el problema esta relacionado a permisos, el permiso que debes requerir es `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en lugar de `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, si pides el primero, es inherente que tienes el segundo (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

Realiza el cambio y comenta:

```
 ...
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
  ...
  ...
```

obviamente definelo en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

No es necesario definir:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: El error sigue siendo el mismo, lo extraño es que solo sucede cuando selecciono la imagen desde google photos.